# Запятая с тире или только тире перед словом "как минимум"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, запятые

Нужна ли запятая вместе с тире в предложении:

*Свадьба — это праздник не только для двоих, но и для гостей и родителей, поэтому пропустить такое мероприятие **, —** как минимум, странно.*

Answer (score 1):

**Свадьба – это праздник не только для двоих, но и для гостей и родителей, поэтому пропустить такое мероприятие – как минимум странно.**

"Как минимум" считается наречием и выделяется запятыми только для интонационного подчеркивания (из справочника "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации). Тире в данном случае также авторское, интонационное. Поэтому можно оставить только тире.